# Why when I pass a dataframe of integers to apply function in R the variable gets transformed?

Tags: r, arguments, apply

I'm quite newbie in R, so please be indulgent. This must be something really simple. I have a function that I would like to execute over every element of a dataframe. Minimal example:

```
agenericfunction = function(pos) {
   print(pos)
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
apply(as.data.frame(1:5), 1, agenericfunction)
```

This is what I get:

```
1:5 
  1 
1:5 
  2 
1:5 
  3 
1:5 
  4 
1:5 
  5 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But if I modify the function like this:

```
agenericfunction = function(pos) {
  print(paste0("_",pos))
}
```

I then get what one would normally expect:

```
[1] "_1"
[1] "_2"
[1] "_3"
[1] "_4"
[1] "_5"
[1] "_1" "_2" "_3" "_4" "_5"
```

I do not understand why my integer 'pos' variable gets converted in the first case into some weird thing that provokes that output. If I use the "class" function on "pos", it always says that it is a integer (in any of the two cases above). Could someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: The "1:5" in case 1 is the name of the dataframe column and the row element, respectively. The result of paste0 on the other hand has no name. And any range/sequence has type integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing in the 1st case is the column name above each integer. Meaning that when the `as.data.frame` is called, it creates a column with `colnames` `1:8`.

If you do `df <- as.data.frame(1:8)` and then `colnames(df)` you will see this:

```
> names(t)
[1] "1:8"
```

As to why its working with `paste0`, `paste0` ignores the column name and just returns the values that are inside. Modifying your function to return `return(paste0(pos))` will yield the result you want.

If you want to avoid that, best create a matrix instead of a data.frame:

```
apply(matrix(1:5), 1, agenericfunction)
```

Output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Ok, understood. I've tested with matrix and you're completely right. Thanks a lot!